# Circular motion - is average velocity enough to tell?

Tags: kinematics

If I knew the exact value of constant centripetal force and the **average velocity** of an object travelling around a circle for time $t$, would that be enough information to determine the final positon of an object? What I mean is what if I had another object, at the same initial position and with identical centripetal force applied to it, which would have a different velocity function $f(t)$, but identical average velocity - would it eventually be in the same place as the first object after time $t$?
Deriving a formula answering this question was beyond my skills.

Comment: Well in your scenario, what's stopping it for there to be a final position? friction? loss of balance between centripetal/centrifugal forces or else?

Comment: What equations do you know -- and of course what variables in those equations don't you know?

Comment: I've defined the centripetal force to be equal in both cases. I thought maybe because of the fact the velocity is squared in the cirlce radius equation, the very knowledge of average velocity doesn't tell us everything - maybe higher velocities

Comment: I defined the centripetal force to be equal in both cases. Maybe because the velocity is squared in the circle radius equation, higher velocities "contribute more" to ball positions than low velocities, and even though the average velocity is the same as of the ball moving with constant speed, they would be in different places.

Comment: The average velocity of anything moving in a circle is zero, so no, that won't be helpful.  Perhaps you mean average *speed*?

Comment: Yes, I mean average speed. A thought experiment tells me to believe the answer to this question is "no": consider an object being at rest for half of the time, and then starting to move twice as fast as the other object. The average speed is identical in both cases, but the position is certianly different - they both covered the same distance, but the turn radius was different. Is my reasoning valid?

Comment: I think I'm missing something.  If an object is moving in a circle, and it has a constant centripetal force, then its speed will be constant.  $f(t)$ is constant.  If you add a tangential force to change its speed, then its path won't be a circle anymore.  You can't have all of these at the same time:  circular motion,  constant centripetal force, variable speed.

Comment: What garyp said plus note that velocity and speed are _different_ physical quantities.

Comment: Isn't the average velocity of something travelling in a circle subject to constant centripetal force zero? Average speed is what you mean right?

Answer (score 1):

Average velocity is defined as:

$$\vec v_\text{avg}=\frac{\vec x_f - \vec x_i}{\Delta t}.$$

Re-arranging yields $\vec x_f = \vec x_i + \vec v_\text{avg}\Delta t$. This alone should be enough to help you answer your question.

You might also be interested in (or have actually meant) average speed:

$$s_\text{avg}=\frac{d_\text{traversed}}{\Delta t},$$

where $d_\text{traversed}$ is the distance traversed. You can also re-arrange this equation to solve for $d_\text{traversed}$ and that might get you what you want if you stick to circular motion and remember that each particle starts at the same location.

---

By the way, note how I approached this problem: You asked about average velocity, so I asked myself what the *definition* of that quantity was, and figured out from there if it could help us. This is a good first step in solving physics problems.